# Can the answers given to questions be customized and used on personal and/or commercial websites without fear of copyright infringement?

Tags: discussion

Can the answers given to questions be customized and used on personal and/or commercial websites without fear of copyright infringement? The question and answer that I am referring to is:

[How to show/hide input value on focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077859/how-to-show-hide-input-value-on-focus)

And the answer given was (the bottom answer):

Answer:    (given by Eren Yeager answered  Apr 26 '14 at 3:46)

Maybe Eren Yeager could best answer this one, but I can't contact her directly.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: [Read this blog post: Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). All the content on Stack Overflow is licensed under [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).